# YouCompleteMe Installation CalledProcessError

Tags: vim, cmake, clang

I have installed Cmake through brew and looked through the bug tracker and SO for other people with this issue and I haven't found anyone that has my issue. Here's the bug from the output:

```
Linking CXX shared library /Users/danni/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycm_core.so
ld: warning: ignoring file ../clang+llvm-3.7.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-14.04/lib/libclang.so.3.7, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): ../clang+llvm-3.7.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-14.04/lib/libclang.so.3.7
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_clang_Comment_getKind", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::DocumentationData::DocumentationData(CXCursor const&) in Documentation.cpp.obj
  "_clang_CompilationDatabase_dispose", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::CompilationDatabase::~CompilationDatabase() in CompilationDatabase.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::CompilationDatabase::~CompilationDatabase() in CompilationDatabase.cpp.obj
  "_clang_CompilationDatabase_fromDirectory", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::CompilationDatabase::CompilationDatabase(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in CompilationDatabase.cpp.obj
  "_clang_CompilationDatabase_getCompileCommands", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::CompilationDatabase::GetCompilationInfoForFile(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in CompilationDatabase.cpp.obj
  "_clang_CompileCommand_getArg", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::CompilationDatabase::GetCompilationInfoForFile(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in CompilationDatabase.cpp.obj
  "_clang_CompileCommand_getDirectory", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::CompilationDatabase::GetCompilationInfoForFile(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in CompilationDatabase.cpp.obj
  "_clang_CompileCommand_getNumArgs", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::CompilationDatabase::GetCompilationInfoForFile(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in CompilationDatabase.cpp.obj
  "_clang_CompileCommands_dispose", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::CompilationDatabase::GetCompilationInfoForFile(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in CompilationDatabase.cpp.obj
  "_clang_CompileCommands_getCommand", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::CompilationDatabase::GetCompilationInfoForFile(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in CompilationDatabase.cpp.obj
  "_clang_CompileCommands_getSize", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::CompilationDatabase::GetCompilationInfoForFile(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in CompilationDatabase.cpp.obj
  "_clang_Cursor_getBriefCommentText", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::DocumentationData::DocumentationData(CXCursor const&) in Documentation.cpp.obj
  "_clang_Cursor_getParsedComment", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::DocumentationData::DocumentationData(CXCursor const&) in Documentation.cpp.obj
  "_clang_Cursor_getRawCommentText", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::DocumentationData::DocumentationData(CXCursor const&) in Documentation.cpp.obj
  "_clang_Cursor_isNull", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::CursorIsValid(CXCursor) in ClangUtils.cpp.obj
  "_clang_FullComment_getAsXML", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::DocumentationData::DocumentationData(CXCursor const&) in Documentation.cpp.obj
  "_clang_codeCompleteAt", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::CandidatesForLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_createIndex", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::ClangCompleter::ClangCompleter() in ClangCompleter.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::ClangCompleter::ClangCompleter() in ClangCompleter.cpp.obj
  "_clang_defaultCodeCompleteOptions", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::CandidatesForLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_defaultDiagnosticDisplayOptions", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::(anonymous namespace)::FullDiagnosticText(void*) in ClangHelpers.cpp.obj
  "_clang_defaultEditingTranslationUnitOptions", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::TranslationUnit(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&, void*) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_defaultReparseOptions", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::TranslationUnit(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&, void*) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::Reparse(std::__1::vector<CXUnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<CXUnsavedFile> >&) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::Reparse(std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_disposeCodeCompleteResults", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::CandidatesForLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_disposeDiagnostic", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::UpdateLatestDiagnostics() in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_disposeIndex", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::ClangCompleter::~ClangCompleter() in ClangCompleter.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::ClangCompleter::~ClangCompleter() in ClangCompleter.cpp.obj
  "_clang_disposeString", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::CXStringToString(CXString) in ClangUtils.cpp.obj
  "_clang_disposeTokens", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::BuildDiagnostic(boost::shared_ptr<void>, CXTranslationUnitImpl*) in ClangHelpers.cpp.obj
  "_clang_disposeTranslationUnit", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::Destroy() in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_equalTypes", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetTypeAtLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_formatDiagnostic", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::(anonymous namespace)::FullDiagnosticText(void*) in ClangHelpers.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getCString", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::CXStringToString(CXString) in ClangUtils.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getCanonicalCursor", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetDeclarationLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetDocsForLocationInFile(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getCanonicalType", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetTypeAtLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getChildDiagnostics", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::(anonymous namespace)::FullDiagnosticText(void*) in ClangHelpers.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getClangVersion", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::ClangVersion() in ClangUtils.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getCompletionAvailability", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::ToCompletionDataVector(CXCodeCompleteResults*) in ClangHelpers.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getCompletionBriefComment", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::CompletionData::CompletionData(CXCompletionResult const&) in CompletionData.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getCompletionChunkCompletionString", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::(anonymous namespace)::OptionalChunkToString(void*, unsigned int) in CompletionData.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getCompletionChunkKind", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::CompletionData::ExtractDataFromChunk(void*, unsigned int, bool&, bool&, bool&) in CompletionData.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::(anonymous namespace)::OptionalChunkToString(void*, unsigned int) in CompletionData.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getCompletionChunkText", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::CompletionData::ExtractDataFromChunk(void*, unsigned int, bool&, bool&, bool&) in CompletionData.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::(anonymous namespace)::OptionalChunkToString(void*, unsigned int) in CompletionData.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getCursor", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::BuildDiagnostic(boost::shared_ptr<void>, CXTranslationUnitImpl*) in ClangHelpers.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetDeclarationLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetCursor(int, int) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetDefinitionLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetTypeAtLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetEnclosingFunctionAtLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetDocsForLocationInFile(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
      ...
  "_clang_getCursorDefinition", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetDefinitionLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getCursorDisplayName", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetEnclosingFunctionAtLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getCursorExtent", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::BuildDiagnostic(boost::shared_ptr<void>, CXTranslationUnitImpl*) in ClangHelpers.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getCursorKind", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::CursorIsValid(CXCursor) in ClangUtils.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::CursorIsReference(CXCursor) in ClangUtils.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::CursorIsDeclaration(CXCursor) in ClangUtils.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getCursorLocation", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetDeclarationLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetDefinitionLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getCursorReferenced", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetDeclarationLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetDocsForLocationInFile(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getCursorSemanticParent", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetEnclosingFunctionAtLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getCursorSpelling", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::DocumentationData::DocumentationData(CXCursor const&) in Documentation.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getCursorType", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::DocumentationData::DocumentationData(CXCursor const&) in Documentation.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetTypeAtLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getDiagnostic", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::UpdateLatestDiagnostics() in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getDiagnosticFixIt", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::BuildDiagnostic(boost::shared_ptr<void>, CXTranslationUnitImpl*) in ClangHelpers.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getDiagnosticInSet", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::(anonymous namespace)::FullDiagnosticText(void*) in ClangHelpers.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getDiagnosticLocation", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::BuildDiagnostic(boost::shared_ptr<void>, CXTranslationUnitImpl*) in ClangHelpers.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getDiagnosticNumFixIts", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::BuildDiagnostic(boost::shared_ptr<void>, CXTranslationUnitImpl*) in ClangHelpers.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getDiagnosticNumRanges", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::BuildDiagnostic(boost::shared_ptr<void>, CXTranslationUnitImpl*) in ClangHelpers.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getDiagnosticRange", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::BuildDiagnostic(boost::shared_ptr<void>, CXTranslationUnitImpl*) in ClangHelpers.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getDiagnosticSeverity", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::BuildDiagnostic(boost::shared_ptr<void>, CXTranslationUnitImpl*) in ClangHelpers.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getDiagnosticSpelling", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::BuildDiagnostic(boost::shared_ptr<void>, CXTranslationUnitImpl*) in ClangHelpers.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getExpansionLocation", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::Location::Location(CXSourceLocation const&) in ClangHelpers.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::Location::Location(CXSourceLocation const&) in Range.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::Location::Location(CXSourceLocation const&) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getFile", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetDeclarationLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetCursor(int, int) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetDefinitionLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetTypeAtLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetEnclosingFunctionAtLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetDocsForLocationInFile(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getFileName", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::CXFileToFilepath(void*) in ClangUtils.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getLocation", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetDeclarationLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetCursor(int, int) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetDefinitionLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetTypeAtLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetEnclosingFunctionAtLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetDocsForLocationInFile(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getNullCursor", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetCursor(int, int) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getNumCompletionChunks", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::CompletionData::CompletionData(CXCompletionResult const&) in CompletionData.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::(anonymous namespace)::OptionalChunkToString(void*, unsigned int) in CompletionData.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getNumDiagnostics", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::UpdateLatestDiagnostics() in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getNumDiagnosticsInSet", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::(anonymous namespace)::FullDiagnosticText(void*) in ClangHelpers.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getRangeEnd", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::Range::Range(CXSourceRange const&) in Range.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getRangeStart", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::Range::Range(CXSourceRange const&) in Range.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getTokenLocation", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::BuildDiagnostic(boost::shared_ptr<void>, CXTranslationUnitImpl*) in ClangHelpers.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getTokenSpelling", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::BuildDiagnostic(boost::shared_ptr<void>, CXTranslationUnitImpl*) in ClangHelpers.cpp.obj
  "_clang_getTypeSpelling", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::DocumentationData::DocumentationData(CXCursor const&) in Documentation.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::GetTypeAtLocation(int, int, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, bool) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_isDeclaration", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::CursorIsDeclaration(CXCursor) in ClangUtils.cpp.obj
  "_clang_isInvalid", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::CursorIsValid(CXCursor) in ClangUtils.cpp.obj
  "_clang_isReference", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::CursorIsReference(CXCursor) in ClangUtils.cpp.obj
  "_clang_parseTranslationUnit", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::TranslationUnit(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::vector<UnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<UnsavedFile> > const&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&, void*) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_reparseTranslationUnit", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::TranslationUnit::Reparse(std::__1::vector<CXUnsavedFile, std::__1::allocator<CXUnsavedFile> >&, unsigned int) in TranslationUnit.cpp.obj
  "_clang_toggleCrashRecovery", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::ClangCompleter::ClangCompleter() in ClangCompleter.cpp.obj
      YouCompleteMe::ClangCompleter::ClangCompleter() in ClangCompleter.cpp.obj
  "_clang_tokenize", referenced from:
      YouCompleteMe::BuildDiagnostic(boost::shared_ptr<void>, CXTranslationUnitImpl*) in ClangHelpers.cpp.obj
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [/Users/danni/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycm_core.so] Error 1
make[2]: *** [ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_support_libs.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [ycm_support_libs] Error 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/danni/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/build.py", line 327, in <module>
    Main()
  File "/Users/danni/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/build.py", line 316, in Main
    BuildYcmdLibs( args )
  File "/Users/danni/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/build.py", line 261, in BuildYcmdLibs
    subprocess.check_call( build_command )
  File "/Users/danni/miniconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--target', 'ycm_support_libs', '--', '-j', '8']' returned non-zero exit status 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./install.py", line 32, in <module>
    Main()
  File "./install.py", line 21, in Main
    subprocess.check_call( [ python_binary, build_file ] + sys.argv[1:] )
  File "/Users/danni/miniconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Users/danni/miniconda/bin/python', '/Users/danni/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/build.py', '--clang-completer']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I just installed the newest version of Vim and CMake via brew, can anybody help me make sense of this issue?

Comment: What is your OS and what command do you run to install YouCompleteMe? Using brew assumes Mac OS, but then warning mentions clang for Unbuntu 14.04. And the error says that something went wrong with architecture (64 bit vs 32 bit). Also if you don't need the completion for C/C++ you can install it without `--clang-complete` flag, it will also be much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm running Mac OSX 10.9.5, I'm using ./install.py --clang-completer

Comment: Did you use Macvim or vim?

Comment: Vim, would using MacVim make a difference?

Comment: The installation manual at github states clearly that MacVim should be used. But I don't know if this is causing the issue.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a bug in the YouCompleteMe setup process and it is good if you report it to their [issue tracker](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues).

What makes me think so:

1) Warning at the top of your output:

```
Linking CXX shared library 
/Users/danni/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycm_core.so

ld: warning: ignoring file 
../clang+llvm-3.7.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-14.04/lib/libclang.so.3.7, 
file was built for unsupported file format
```

2) The relevant clang version detection is [here](https://github.com/Valloric/ycmd/blob/2454bad9fab575603b112c9131ae48e69bc871ba/cpp/ycm/CMakeLists.txt#L49) (if I am not mistaken).

And it selects the wrong clang for download (one for Ubuntu 14.04).

The logic to select clang to download is: if "APPLE" variable is defined - get mac os version if it is windows - then win version otherwise for 64 bit system use "x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-14.04".

Possible workarounds:

1) If you don't need C-family completion, use `./install.py` without --clang-completer flag

2) You install proper clang version manually and tell YouCompleteMe to use it.
I didn't try it, but it the command to use installed clang seems to be `./install.py --clang-completer --system-libclang`.
You may already have clang installed if you have XCode. Otherwise check the [full installation guide](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#full-installation-guide) in the YCM documentation.

3) Brute force - change the YCM source to fetch the correct version. This is not very good way to solve the problem, because you will need to remove your changes before updating YCM and put them back after update, but this way you can also confirm the bug in the setup process:

- Open /Users/danni/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/CMakeLists.txt
- Add `set( APPLE TRUE )` at the top.
- Run `./install.py --clang-completer` again.
- Note: I didn't actually try this method, but think that it could work. If something goes wrong, try to search for other 'CMakeLists.txt' files in the ycmd folder and add `set( APPLE TRUE )` to them.

Comment: Edited point (2), changed the link to clang docs to the full installation guide in the YCM docs.